# node dependencies not found when running pnpm install

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules, pnpm

I have been using pnpm instead npm for my new projects to try it out and i have ecountered an issue.

I will take my nuxt project as an example.

I first setup my project using the following command:

```bash
pnpx nuxi init my-project
```

I then install a dependency, let's say axios

```bash
pnpm add axios
```

when importing axios in a component i get the following error

```
import axios from 'axios'
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module axios

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: {enabled: true},
})
TS2552: Cannot find name defineNuxtConfig.
```

to fix the issue i try to reinstall the dependencies by running `pnpm install` but the issue remains.

i figured i could fix the issue by running `npm install`.

For information:

- commands are ran in a wsl2 environment (Ubuntu)
- my IDE is Webstorm but the error is also present with VSCode
- there are also issues with other modules and configuration files such as nuxt.config.ts
- the issue also happens with React projects
- the Volar Typescript service specific to Vue is running but the issue is also present with the Main Typescript service

My guess is that my IDE does not know where my node modules are even though the are clearly present in the project but i have no idea to be honst.

Do you have any idea where the issue could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the issue comes from wsl2 that doesn't properly support symlink as of November 2023.

See:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54790/webstorm-cant-find-any-package-with-pnpm-in-wsl2#focus=Comments-27-5770391.0-0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Consider include the `.npmrc` file in the root of your project, with `shamefully-hoist=true`. Check if this help with your issue.